# how to send data from express.js to react without API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I want to create a Multi Page APP using react and express.

**I am confused about how to retrieve data sent by the express into react without using the API.**

I wonder if react can retrieve the data stored in html props sent by express?
maybe this question is a little weird. actually I have never created a website with just an express. I always use react and retrieve data through the API and create a Single Page App.

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

React and express are playing two different roles. 
React Is your front end.
Express is the backend. 
Those are logically separated layers. The preferred way to load data from backend to frontend is through API calls.

Comment: so if I only use express.js I still have to do the fetch API? unlike PHP that doesn't need to require an API?

Comment: Of course, you can do it the PHP way with express. Just use your preferred templating engine with express. I prefer the templating engine called handlebars Its syntax is very much similar to pure HTML. connect your favorite templating engine to the express as a middleware. Then you can render HTML to the user as PHP does.

Answer (score 0):

`I wonder if react can retrieve the data stored in html props sent by express?`

Yes it can. I'm not sure what you mean by "html props", but you can store the needed data as data-attributes when sending back the html to the front-end, and then pull it out of the DOM like so ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes ).

Depending on how you plan to use it, you can just pull that data out for one-time usage or push it into your state.

Answer (score 0):

The first way I could think it is to use the parameters in url.

For example, if your website has url like `http://localhost/` and you will use url `http://localhost/api/data?` to receive data from express.js.

Then in your `express.js`, after getting request from your react, you can use:

res.redirect(`http://localhost/api/${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))})`

where `res` is the response object and `data` is the data you want to send to data, which is assumed to be an object.

In your `react`, you can retrieve your data with the following steps:
- implement a component and set `/api/data?` as the route of this component;
- in the component, retrieve the data as `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(this.props.match.params.data))`